# CentOS7 fails to start without monitor

Tags: centos, boot, grub

When I used Windows 7 on the same PC, I didn't have this problem. Now I can't start my server if monitor is not connected. When I turn it on without monitor, I can't hear HDD loading and also can't connect via SSH. I tried to add **nomodeset** to my /etc/default/grub, and then **grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg**, but it doesn't fix anything. Booting with keyboard doesn't work, monitor is a rootcause.

What can I do?

Comment: What is displayed when you connect the monitor *after* it has failed to boot?

Comment: when i connect monitor after boot, monitor doesn't show anything at all, i thing its a bug of hdmi

Comment: Try booting it with just a keyboard attached, does it boot?

Comment: Did you update the firmware between upgrading from W7 to CentOS?

Comment: no, hardware and bios are the same absolutely

Comment: @MichaelProkopec, updated question.

Comment: Is there only one type of output or are there others?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by output.

Answer (score 1):

You could try these dummy plugs as options:

[HDMI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074FT1P8M)
[VGA](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwiBg6DjgsPgAhWGn58KHZQlCEUYABADGgJxYg&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAASE-RoTyUnHCkPrHT7Jmd_Nql5dJM&sig=AOD64_1odXPXYQEuag2dIEzs-Y1zfcpj2A&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwiRyZrjgsPgAhVPnOAKHd0KCgUQ9aACCDs&adurl=)
[DVI](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwj_58eLg8PgAhWPnp8KHfmAD2YYABADGgJxYg&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAASE-Ro_xk3i95R-JAwP6kNZ0QGbrQ&sig=AOD64_1t3YxJ96DIwSFEsTxXVJHhzeNUFA&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwj1scKLg8PgAhXpc98KHe2GAfIQ9aACCDo&adurl=)

Comment: HW problem, HW solution: **+1** although _technically_ off topic.

Comment: This is software problem, because Windows7 works correctly on same hardware.

Comment: Windows talks directly to the BIOS these days and does things to make using it easier, without notifying the user what it did. So there is no telling what it did or is doing.